# Missing local commands after running zopeskel on windows

Tags: windows, plone, paster, zopeskel

I try to create an archetype with zopskel/paster on my newly installed plone 4.2. I have adjusted the buildout.cfg (see below) to get zopeskel.exe and paster.exe generated in the bin folder.

Howerver when I run zopeskel as follows (in develop-eggs folder):
..\bin\zopeskel.exe archetype
I get an IOError (see below for output)

From what I understand I should now have local commands when running paster (like add). However when I now run paster (in the develop-eggs/nortek.test03) folder there is no commands.

Is there a bug/flaw in the zopeskel or am I doing something wrong? How do I proceed?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Plone42\bin\zopeskel-script.py", line 16, in <module>
    zopeskel.zopeskel_script.run()
  File "c:\plone42\eggs\zopeskel-2.21.2-py2.6.egg\zopeskel\zopeskel_script.py", line 397, in run
    command.run( [ '-q', '-t', template_name ] + optslist )
  File "c:\plone42\eggs\pastescript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg\paste\script\command.py", line 238, in run
    result = self.command()
  File "c:\plone42\eggs\pastescript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg\paste\script\create_distro.py", line 170, in command
    egg_info_dir = pluginlib.egg_info_dir(output_dir, dist_name)
  File "c:\plone42\eggs\pastescript-1.7.5-py2.6.egg\paste\script\pluginlib.py", line 135, in egg_info_dir
    % ', '.join(all))
IOError: No egg-info directory found (looked in .\nortek.test03\.\nortek.test03.egg-info, .\nortek.test03\CHAN
GES.txt\nortek.test03.egg-info, .\nortek.test03\CONTRIBUTORS.txt\nortek.test03.egg-info, .\nortek.test03\docs\
nortek.test03.egg-info, .\nortek.test03\MANIFEST.in\nortek.test03.egg-info, .\nortek.test03\nortek\nortek.test
03.egg-info, .\nortek.test03\README.txt\nortek.test03.egg-info, .\nortek.test03\setup.cfg\nortek.test03.egg-in
fo, .\nortek.test03\setup.py\nortek.test03.egg-info)
```

My buildout.cfg is identical to default except the following:

```
parts =
    zeo
    instance
    run-instance
    run-zeo
    service
    service-zeo
    zopeskel

[zopeskel]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
unzip = true
eggs =
    Paste
    PasteScript
    ZopeSkel
```

**[EDIT]**
I tried to follow the instructions in the link provided. However there are several problems that occure:
* no paste script is generated in bin folder
* I still get exactly the same IOError issue
* There are no local commands

I put output from the different commands I ran onto this link:
http://pastie.org/4664202

So please help me as I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Please use the upgraded instructions:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getstarted/paste.html

Wherever you found those instructions please tell it to us and we will try take down the bad instructions.

Comment: I still get the same problem. (please see comments above)

Comment: Can you check if you have any ZopeSkel packages installed in system Python folder? They might take override and must be deleted.

Comment: I have removed all zopeskel eggs and executable and ran the buildout again. However I still do not get paster.exe generated and I still get an error when at the end when running zopeskel

Comment: I have still not solved this issue? Anybody that has some suggestions?

Comment: Sorry. It is most likely something to do with Windows. I reported this issue in ZopeSkel bug tracker, but we have not solution yet.